# Cocos2d-x cross platform game development

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, windows-phone, cocos2d-x

I want to make a game with my friends on iOs, Android, WP operating systems. We decided to use a cocos2d-x and develop the core of the game on C++. What will be the right way of developing so that we can write the game all together simultaneously but just build the project differently on every platform.
 We thought of writing the core of the game in C++ in Visual Studio, but there is the problem: How can we test it fast on every platform? How people usually develop multi-platform projects?.
 Also we would really like to hear some recommendations about the source controlling of the whole project. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to develop a game on Cocos 2Dx is to

- Develop Complete Game for one platform most probably iOS or Windows.
- Port your game to other platforms.Fix minor bugs that occurs.
- You can use GitHub to Work in groups.
- Make sure you test your apps on devices because some features are
  platform specific like ads etc.

Answer (score 1):

For source control you have several options such as Git or SVN. Personally I quite like Git as it doesn't require a central server as it is peer to peer. That means if it all goes wrong with your host you still have a full copy. In terms of good and repository hosting I would take a look at https://bitbucket.org/

Answer (score 0):

To test on iOS I believe you'd better got a Mac instead of windows box.